# maximized height on div bound to bottom

Tags: css, html

```
<body style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;">container
        <div style="width: 200px; margin-top: 100px; float: left;">
            left
        </div>
        <div style="width: 728px; float: left;">
            <div style="height: 100px;">
                1
            </div>
            <div style="height: 150px;">
                2
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom: 0; bottom: 0; height: 100%;">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

DIV `1` has a fixed height,

DIV `2` changes its height through jQuery

DIV `3` has to stretch as much as possible, after `2` down to `bottom: 0;`

What styles are missing in `3` ?

I also want `container` to be centered.

Comment: You need not define height:100% in 3rd div. If height is not defined, it will automatically adjust itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without Javascript with `css tables`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/mW2zS/1/)**

Comment: `container` should be centered in body and also cover `left`, but your solution fixes the main problem I have with height. great!

Comment: can you please have a look why mine is not working now http://jsfiddle.net/ZVQ5d/

Comment: @DanFromGermany You need to set height:100% on the html element as well see this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ZVQ5d/1/   ... And don't forget... If this answered your question  mark as answer ;)

Comment: I will accept your answer because it's not using Javascript. It doesn't work in my case as I wanted it, because I place a google maps inside the stretched div which uses `position: absolute;` and that gets rendered outside the box. if you have any idea left: http://woisteinebank.de/dev2.html (line 236-294)

Answer (score 0):

Thx to the guy who deleted his answer, it was close to be working.
`height` is somehow ignored, but using `top` and `position: absolute;` it worked.
When DIV `2` resizes, there must be an event triggered resizing DIV `3` tho:

```
<body style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;text-align:center">container
        <div style="width: 200px; margin-top: 100px; float: left;">
            left
        </div>
        <div style="width: 728px; float: left;">
        <div style="height: 100px;" id="a">
            1
        </div>
        <div style="height: 150px;" id="b">
            2
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: red; position: absolute; bottom: 0;" id="test">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').css('top', $('#a').height() + $('#b').height());
    });
</script>
```